# How to download CSV file from the web with dowload URL Swift

Tags: swift, google-apps-script, google-sheets, download, nsfilemanager

So I need to get the data from a google sheet (which I'm trying to generate the link for, not sure), but I have a dummy link which works. I wrote this code to download the CSV file from the spreadsheet and then parse it into an array. When I print the parsed CSV, I simply get an array with one element which is App/... some location in the system.

```
 func getDataFromSheet(){
        let urlString = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT2-wSYyvNPeF7W3HGyw_MPhMXfuQwzBMAx8SjBOWR5PlZpeTZUCmKuPo044wYKLpweZe7ucUVl0yT5/pub?gid=1025030631&single=true&output=csv"

        // 2
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
            // 3
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: imageUrl) { (tempFileUrl, response, error) in
                
                // 4
                if let imageTempFileUrl = tempFileUrl {
                    do {
                        
                  
                            let content = try String(data: imageTempFileUrl.dataRepresentation, encoding: .utf8)
                            let parsedCSV: [String] = content!.components(
                                separatedBy: "\n"
                            ).map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")[0] }
                        print(parsedCSV.description)
                        
                        
                    
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: "It's not working as intended." What does this mean? Have you used the debugger or print statements? Where does it get to? Where does it diverge from what you expect?

Comment: @jnpdx good point, just updated it to be more specific

Comment: `.downloadTask` delivers a temporary file location saved on the device. But I am kind of puzzeled as naming the var `tempFileUrl` should give that away. Just use a `dataTask`  to get the response as `Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example code, works for me:

```
func getDataFromSheet() {
    let urlString = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT2-wSYyvNPeF7W3HGyw_MPhMXfuQwzBMAx8SjBOWR5PlZpeTZUCmKuPo044wYKLpweZe7ucUVl0yT5/pub?gid=1025030631&single=true&output=csv"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { print("error"); return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let content = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                let parsedCSV: [String] = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                // all data
                print(parsedCSV, "\n")
                // first line
                print(parsedCSV.map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")}[0], "\n")
                // second line
                print(parsedCSV.map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")}[1], "\n")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. I'm new to swift, but this makes sense now.